# Parsing specific JSON with Gson

Tags: java, android, gson

I'm currently trying to parse a JSON response with the following structure using Gson:

```
{
  data {
   "1": {
      "name": "John Doe"
  },
   "2": {
      "name": "John Doe"
  },
  ...
}
```

My response class:

```
class Response {
  Map<String, ModelObj> data;
}
```

and model class:

```
class ModelObj {
  String name;
}
```

But what I can't figure out is how to simply map everything to a single List where the id is placed within the ModelObj without having them separate as key/value pairs in a Map. So ideally my response class would be:

```
class Response {
  List<ModelObj> data;
}
```

and model class:

```
class ModelObj {
  String id;
  String name;
}
```

How would this be accomplished?

Comment: The problem is that you have keys that change from object to object. The keys corresponde to atributes. And you can ‘t use reflectaron to and or change an atribute. So gson is not the best tool to parse these kind of json.

Comment: Your JSON response is not good and isn't suitable for Gson. To use Gson, you will need to have fixed number of fields. If it is possible, instead of returning object in the `data` field, return an array.

Answer (score 0):

```
 [
   {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "John Doe"
    }, 
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "John Doe"
    }
 ]
```

If your response is of above form then only you will get the list of model object and you will get Array of ModelObj

then use below code to convert to List

> ```
> public <T> List<T> getObjectToList(String json, Class<T[]> ObjectArrayClass) {
>         return Arrays.asList(gson.fromJson(json, ObjectArrayClass));
>     }
> ```

```
List< ModelObj > arrayList = getObjectToList(jsonResponseString, ModelObj[].class);
```